# Is there a common pattern allowing to extend existing state in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I'm designing a library that tracks its internal state and I want to allow users add their own custom state. What kind of interface would users expect to have for this purpose?

To be more precise, this question is primarily about adding independent state to an existing state such that the scope (or lifecycle) of the state would remain unchanged.

Comment: Typically one uses a type parameter.

Comment: It's important to clarify here whether the _users_ only interact with a complete compiled program, or they compile their own program using your library. Either way, the question could use some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parsec** is a pretty famous library that uses the kind of user state
that you mentioned in the question. It might be helpful to see what it
does. I'm using [this documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html).

What does Hoogle say about the type of the **ParsecT** monad transformer?

> ParsecT s u m a is a parser with stream type s, user state type u,
>   underlying monad m and return type a.
>
> Parsec is strict in the user state.
>
> If this is undesirable, simply use a data type like data Box a = Box a
>   and the state type Box YourStateType to add a level of indirection.

Next, let's see how the module's authors allow its users to manipulate the
user state.  We can read this state by using the following function:

```
getState :: Monad m => ParsecT s u m u
```

The state can be written using the following function:

```
putState :: Monad m => u -> ParsecT s u m ()
```

The state can be transformed using this function:

```
modifyState :: Monad m => (u -> u) -> ParsecT s u m ()
```

Finally, we take a look at the way in which the initial user state is passed
to a function of the type `ParsecT s u m a`:

```
runParser :: Stream s Identity t => 
             Parsec s u a -> u -> SourceName -> s -> 
             Either ParseError a
```

I haven't seen complaints about the interface Parsec uses
for user state, so the functions above ought to be a good first step
for your library's design.